# Canvas max height limitation on IE

Tags: javascript, html

I am generating gantt chart using DIV,CANVAS.

I am using canvas to draw lines and I'm having huge data which makes height my chart more than 9000px.

There is  no problem on Firefox but CANVAS max limit is something around 8192px in IE
because of this limit, lines drawn after that limit are not showing up.

Is there any workaround which will overcome this IE's Canvas max-height limitation...

```
<DIV id="parentDiv" style="z-index:0; height: 900px; overflow:auto ;overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:hidden;background-color:#fff;opacity: 1;position: absoulte;" >' +
        '<canvas id="c" width="' + vChartWidth + 'px"  style="background-color:#000;z-index:1;position: absolute;pointer-events: none;opacity:0.5;"></canvas>'+
        '<DIV class=scroll2 id=rightside>' 

'</DIV>'
```

I am creating table inside rightside DIV .table rows equals to number of tasks.

Comment: The best workaround I see is to split your graphics into several `<canvas>` elements.

Comment: i am thinking of creating multiple canvas but how will i come to know when to use next canvas.As to draw line i need to get it context of canvas. how to decide the height is crossing the max-limit dynamically